# RatingBar set selector programmatically

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ratingbar

In my Custom Ratingbar class I want to set its selector programatically.

This works and change the color states.

```
 LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#62CFDE"),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for filled stars
    stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for half filled stars
    stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#62CFDE"),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for empty stars
```

But I want to set images in selector, but this code is not working.

```
 StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.progressDrawable}, selectedImage);
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.progress}, selectedImage);
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.secondaryProgress}, backgroundImage);
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.background}, backgroundImage);
    setBackground(states);
```

Please suggest me how can I set the selector of my Ratingbar programatically.

Comment: Did you try ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(states); ?

Comment: @DavidRauca yes, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have done following to achieve this.

Added a layerlist xml, here I have given a temparary  image for all three states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rect" />

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rect" />

<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rect" />
```

Now at run time we will find items by id and change their images.

```
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)   getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ratingbar_selector);
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, backgroundImage);
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.secondaryProgress, backgroundImage);
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress, selectedImage);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setProgressDrawableTiled(ld);
    }
```